# PHP class methods - deciding when to make them static or not

Tags: php

When creating class methods what factors should be considered with respect to making them static or not?

For instance:

```
class Test1
{
  public function xyz()
   {
     //code
   }
}
```

versus

```
class Test2
    {
      public static function xyz()
       {
         //code
       }
    }
```

I am aware that including the word static (as in class Test2) makes use of $this->xyz() impossible because static functions are associated with the class - not an instance of the class.

Comment: It's easy: never use `static`

Comment: @Krimson: I don't see your point

Comment: @Marty yes, exactly like that

Comment: @zerkms sorry, I meant the wrong thing oops. My point is, if we never use static, then we would always have to create a new instance of an object if we want to use a method. Isn't this bad? Like if you have a static method, you can just do `Class::method();` If you dont, then you have to always create a new instance

Comment: @Krimson: it's not bad. If you don't want an object - don't create a class, but a function.

Comment: @zerkms I see but what if you are creating a stateless library which has a lot of function? You might end up having a high probability of 2 generic functions having the same name. Putting static functions in a class is a good way to organize a group of functions. Don't you think so?

Comment: @Krimson: you can put them into different namespaces, cannot you?

Comment: @zerkms That works too!, thanks was just curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always make utility functions static. `sqrt()` of `Math` class is an example. 
Also, if the function has nothing to do with the state of the object, make it static.